# Unity Launcher not shown

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 and tried login. Everything worked fine. Then i installed compiz config settings manager.

and i do not know what i have changed, now i do not see unity launcher when logged into ubuntu. when i login in classic mode i see all panels and tasks, but when logged in unity mode, i do not see any think except the files on desktop.

Thank you

Surya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open Compiz Config Settings Manager and select the desktop catagory and ensure that 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin' checkbox is ticked as below;

[image]